# LazyColumn does not show me the list of items

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm just learning how to use LayzyColumn. The LazyColumn does not show me the list of items. When I click the button, the items that are loaded in the list are not displayed.

Here my code:

```
@Composable
fun MainContent() {

    val list = remember { mutableListOf<String>() }

    LazyColumn(
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(12.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp)
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(list) { index, item ->
            Card(
                backgroundColor = Color(0xFFF7C2D4),
                elevation = 4.dp
            ) {
                Row(
                    Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(12.dp),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                    Text(text = item.takeLast(5), Modifier.weight(1F))
                }

            }
        }
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(12.dp),
        Alignment.BottomEnd
    ) {
        FloatingActionButton(onClick = { list.add(UUID.randomUUID().toString()) }) {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Add, contentDescription = "")

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Compose cannot track changes of plain kotlin types. You need to use Compose mutable states.

In this case `mutableStateListOf` should be used instead of `mutableListOf`.

I suggest you start with [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/mymWGMy9pYI) which explains the basic principles of why do you need to use state in Compose. You can continue deepening your knowledge with state in Compose [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state).